# Change of displayed images for webp versions

Tags: images

I've got in my uploads folder in Wordpress all of images converted to webp - so now i've got in uploads 2 versions of each image: 1. jpg's/png's and 2. webp version.

Images was converted to webp on the server side.

How to bulk change all of png/jpg versions displayed on my website for webp version?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying you've made edits to the PNG/JPEG and want to update the WEBP? Or do you want to regenerate them? How are your webp images being created? Or are these the image sizes such as medium/full/thumbnail that WP generates on upload? Are you using a plugin to do that?

Comment: @TomJNowell i generetad webp files for each png/jpg file in my "uploads" folder - i made in on servers side. Now I want to change in wordpress to display the webp - newly generated versions without any plugins.

Comment: How? Are you aware that WP can generate webp images natively without needing you to manually generate them? And that if you use the native functionality WP will automatically use the webp versions?

Comment: @TomJNowell how to achieve that??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.